# Possible bug with answer acceptance

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

On my [profile summary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud) at the moment I post this question it can be seen that [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/966095/55235) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965970/propositional-logic-for-which-natural-numbers-n-are-there-elements-of-mathc) is accepted. It has been like this for few hours.

However, it can be seen in [my reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud?tab=reputation) that the answer acceptance is not shown. This can also be verified by inspecting my answer for $\color{green}{\large \checkmark}$, it is missing.

I asked the questioner if he accepted my answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967308/propositional-logic-conditions-for-a-sequence-to-be-an-element-of-mathcall-0/967407?noredirect=1#comment1986397_967407) comment. The user [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967308/propositional-logic-conditions-for-a-sequence-to-be-an-element-of-mathcall-0/967407?noredirect=1#comment1986408_967407) he didn't.

So in my summary the answer is showing as accepted, even though it isn't.

**Update:** Another answer to the question was accepted and that seems to have fixed the bug. I also lost 15 reputation points. I wasn't sure, but I was under the impression that I had indeed kept the reputation from the non-existent answer acceptances, so everything seems to be fine now.

Comment: The [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/965970/timeline) shows that your answer *was* in fact accepted at some point, and it doesn't show that it was unaccepted.

Comment: @Asaf: Oddly (or not), the moderator timeline for the question does _not_ show that it was ever accepted.

Comment: Possible explanation: the OP misclicked, resulting in rapid accept-unaccept, which the software, possibly hampered by network gremlins, did not handle 100% correctly.

Comment: @Arthur: That's as odd as 12 lumps of sugar in a cup of coffee.

Comment: @CareBear: So what you are actually saying is that... http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: What am I supposed to do with (bug) questions that go ignored by the SE people? Should I expect to get an answer from them? Will someone come explain what happened and confirm that everything is OK?

Comment: @AsafKaragila How does one get to a question's timeline simply by clicking on links?

Comment: @GitGud The feature request [Add a link to the timeline of a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) is tagged [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. I don't understand why they think it's not useful. The timeline is much more clear, informative and aesthetically pleasing than the edit's history (I always get lost in the editing history).

Comment: There are at least two user scripts to be found on StackApps that add the function of a timeline link.

Comment: @GitGud So, in November 2011 someone  pointed out a typo in the SE code. It was fixed last week. Anna Lear, who fixed the bug, remarked ["We're really running the risk that folks will start to expect timely bug fixes around here"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240629/). And now we see the result: you are already expecting timely reaction. Rather, mark the fall of 2017 on your calendar to check back on this.

Comment: But more seriously, this bug report is more difficult to handle than others because there are no steps to reproduce the bug. It just happened this one time, and we've no clue to what made it happen. If a developer can't reproduce a bug,  they are unlikely to find what causes it.

Comment: @CareBear xD I do expect a timely reaction, even if it's just confirming there is a bug and that they've taken notice of it. As it is, I might be compelled to think that I'm being ignored.

Comment: @CareBeer: If SE were the developers of bash, the Shell Shock bug would have appeared on the bugs trucker three decades ago (which is a few years before bash was released).